# Extract Unique Class Names from Tags

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping (for me) relatively large amounts of data into a beautifulsoup object.  The result of the typical scrape is 600 pages or more of html tags, with many nested tables.  I'm trying to understand the structure better so I can pull the data out of the tables efficiently.

There are up to 500 tables in these soup objects, with many "repeat" table classes.  Below are two examples.

```
<table class="TableClass1">
<table class="TableClass2">
```

There might be 250 of each of these in my document of 500 tables, so its hard to see that there are only two unique types while looking through the 600 pages of html.

**How can I pull a list of unique class names for just table tags, out of the soup object?** The result would show a list like so:

```
<table class="TableClass1">
<table class="TableClass2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want only to show unique class names for just `<table>` tags. You can use `set()` for that (or `collections.Counter`).

For example:

```
txt = '''
<table class="TableClass1"></table>
<table class="TableClass2"></table>
<table class="TableClass2"></table>
<table class="TableClass2"></table>
'''

from collections import Counter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print('Unique class names:')
uniq = set(' '.join(t['class']) for t in soup.select('table[class]'))
print( uniq )

print()

print('Count of class names:')
c = Counter(' '.join(t['class']) for t in soup.select('table[class]'))
print( c )
```

Prints:

```
Unique class names:
{'TableClass1', 'TableClass2'}

Count of class names:
Counter({'TableClass2': 3, 'TableClass1': 1})
```